# How to show number of available items for each filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, nhibernate

In short, my problem is about displaying the number of items available for each filter.

I have the following entities:

Of course, I have other entities such as tags, which I have removed to make things simpler.

```
public class Category {
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public int? ParentId {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

```
public class Product {
   public int Id { get; set; }        
   public int CategoryId { get; set; }
   public int SubcategoryId { get; set; }   
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public bool IsPaid { get; set; }
   public string Level { get; set; }
   public string Grade { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to create a search page similar to what you can see on [Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/courses/development):

As you can see on the linked page, when the user has selected a category or subcategory, the number of items in other subcategories will also be displayed.
Or when filtering items based on `Free`, the number of `Paid` items can also be seen.

I think the only way is to use multiple queries. in such a way that all filters are applied once to get the search results.
Then, to get the number of items related to each filter, run a query by applying all filters except that filter and using grouping by (and count) that filter!

Is there a better way?

Considering the number of necessary queries, isn't it better to read the entire data of all items in a category from the database and execute other queries in memory?

I should mention that the number of items in my project (and of course Udemy) is large! For example, there may be 10,000 or even more items in a category.

I'm using ASP.NET & C# & NHibernate as ORM. I want to query using LINQ (IQueryable).

It would be very helpful if someone could write a sample query.

Update: I don't think this question is opinion-based!

I have a question about the scientific and practical difference between the two approaches.

I have accurately described the project and the work I have done.

Now my question is exactly about the difference in efficiency of receiving all data and querying in memory or multiple queries and receiving less data.

I don't think that this question is subject to people's opinions when we are talking about a specific technology and entities. From a scientific point of view, this question can be answered for someone who has enough knowledge and experience.

Comment: I would guess that getting all Data will be more inefficient. Just the amount of data to stream. Also the database can't use indexes alone to count but has to read the data from disk which should be slower. Without measuring the exact scenario it is hard to tell though

Comment: What you are describing is a faceted search interface. You could do it yourself with multiple queries as you have suggested or use an external search indexer that can do it for you. I have used Azure Cognitive Search in the past, but for smaller projects I just run a bunch of group by with count queries in parallel

Answer (score 1):

Normally, at design level, websites like Udemy or sites that have a large data, use redis db or elk to sync the data at different intervals because the read operations on redis or elk are way faster than the read operations on SQL or any RDBMS. I would suggest you to use these alternatives.

But if you want a easier solution, schedule a job that runs every hour and calculates all the data based on different filter and store in a database. In this case, you are doing a trade off between speed and accuracy. As you mentioned the data you have is more than 10k, no user is going to go through every page and count to see if it matches with the displayed number or no.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But you should keep in mind that the number of parameters is generally very large. For example, the system has several thousand tags, and the combination of these tags and other parameters creates thousands of filters.
But in general I understand your advice. I originally intended to save each users search after calculation so that it would not be recalculated later for other users.
Here, my question was mostly about comparing the efficiency of querying for initial calculation.

Comment: As a simple calculation, I have to say that the number of combinations of different filters, even without tags (topics), is about 200 * 10^15.
I don't think Udemy queries this number of records for each search and keeps this number of records updated.